# iOSで画面の一部を固定したスクロールの実現方法

Tags: swift, ios

xcode8 & swiftでiPad用のアプリを作っています。
Storyboard & Autolayoutを使っています。
iOS10.xがターゲットです。

UIScrollViewの中にUITableViewを入れて上下左右共に画面よりも大きな表を表示し、上下左右にスクロールして表示ができています。(↓こんなイメージ)

[image: 表全体のスクロール]

現在、画面の一部(例えば1列目)のみ左右固定にして2列目以降をスクロールさせようとしていますが、どうすれば実現できるのか見当が付きません。(↓こんなイメージ)

[image: 一部固定のスクロール]

何かわかる方がおられたら教えていただけないでしょうか？
「ここを見れば」とか「この本を見れば」とかでも構いません。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView`と`UIScrollView`の組み合わせで実現するのはあまり向いてないと思います。できなくはないですが、制御しなければならないことがすごくたくさんになるのでとても大変です。

`UICollectionView`を使うことを検討してみてはいかがですか？`UICollectionView`には`sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds`というプロパティがあるので、もしそれで望みの動作が実現できるなら、それが一番簡単だと思います。

そうでない場合、`UICollectionView`のレイアウトをカスタマイズして、固定ヘッダーを実現する方法があります。
具体的には`layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind(elementKind:atIndexPath indexPath:)`でスクロールの左端（=`contentOffset.x`）に常に張り付くようにします。

少し古いですがこちらの記事が参考になると思います。
http://dativestudios.com/blog/2015/01/10/collection_view_sticky_headers/

似たような画面をかなり汎用的に実現できる既存のライブラリとして、
https://github.com/stuffrabbit/SwiftSpreadsheet

があります。こちらは`UICollectionView`を用いてスプレッドシートのようなUIを実現するためのカスタムレイアウトを提供しています。これがそのまま使えないとしても、コードは非常に参考になると思います。

もう一つは私が作ったものですが
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView

というのもあります。これは`UIScrollView`の組み合わせで実現しています。上記のライブラリと比べるとかなりコードが複雑なことがわかると思います。

これらを参考にして、やりたいことにマッチするアーキテクチャを選択するのが良いと思います。

Comment: これから詳しく見てみますが、私がやりたいことそのもののように思います。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

名前のビューとその他のビューを分けて２つ作れば良いのではないでしょうか？
それぞれ、UIScrollViewDelegateを設定し、互いにスクロールを伝達しあえば良いとおもいます。

Comment: これは私も考えたのですが、互いのスクロールのずれが目立つのではないかと懸念しています。